# Replace the string that is between nth occurring pipe symbols

Tags: java

```
    [ACCT_SKEY|ACCOUNT_NBR|ACCOUNT_OFFICER|ACCRUAL_BASIS_CD|ADJUSTABLE_TYPE_CD|AMRT_TERM|AMRT_TERM_MULT|AMRT_TYPE_CD]
```

I need to replace the String "ACCRUAL_BASIS_CD" within the 3rd and 4th occuring pipe symbols. How do i achieve this in JAVA

Comment: Have you tried anything ? If yes than please share your code.

Comment: There are a lot of ways. But first you gotta try it yourself. Show us what you did so far and then we can help you.